# Issue with Confluent JDBC Source connector

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm getting the below issue while trying to use the confluent for kafka-connect. I'm trying to follow the demo given at https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/

Error:

```
./bin/confluent load jdbc_source_mysql_foobar_01 -d /tmp/kafka-connect-jdbc-source.json
{
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

{
  "error_code": 400,
  "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=root&password=tiger for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=root&password=tiger\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=root&password=tiger for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?user=root&password=tiger\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

Comment: Did you make following step: `To use the JDBC connector, you’ll need to make available the relevant JDBC driver for your source database. The connector ships with drivers for PostgreSQL and sqlite—for all others download the appropriate JAR and place it in share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc. You can find the relevant downloads here for MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, and Teradata.`?

Comment: Yes, but I still get the same issue. I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar.

Comment: Ok maybe I needed to restart kafka-connect after placing the jar. Its up now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to restart Kafka Connect after making new JARs available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message `No suitable driver found for` means, that proper jdbc driver cannot be found.

According to article to fix above error you need to place appropriate jdbc driver in `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`

> To use the JDBC connector, you’ll need to make available the relevant JDBC driver for your source database. The connector ships with drivers for PostgreSQL and sqlite—for all others download the appropriate JAR and place it in share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc. You can find the relevant downloads here for MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, and Teradata.

After copying jars, you need to restart Kafka Connect