# JDBC Kafka Connector with Legacy Database

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, rmi, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to use kafka-jdbc-connector (both source and sink) with a very old database (cloudscape).
I have the JDBC driver of this database.
I put the driver in the "/share/java/kafka/connect/jdbc" folder of Confluent (version 5) and created the properties file.

```
name=test-source-cloud-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-cloud-jdbc-
```

When I launch the connector, the logs are:

```
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Finding best dialect for JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:119)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect Db2DatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect DerbyDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect GenericDatabaseDialect scored 10 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect MySqlDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect OracleDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,582] DEBUG Dialect PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Dialect SapHanaDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Dialect SqlServerDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Dialect SqliteDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Dialect SybaseDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Dialect VerticaDatabaseDialect scored 0 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:126)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,583] DEBUG Using dialect GenericDatabaseDialect with score 10 against JDBC subprotocol 'cloudscape' and source 'jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB' (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects:132)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,587] ERROR Failed to create job for ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/CloudscapeProperties.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:102)
[2019-01-31 11:23:36,588] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:cloudscape:rmi://localhost:1099/CloudscapeDB
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
```

I guess there is an issue with the fact that the JDBC Driver is very old (it uses JAVA 1.3).
The driver uses RMI protocol to communicate.
If I run a very simple JAVA RMI client to query the DB using the RmiJdbc.jar and cloudscape.jar (the drivers), I am albe to query the DB and get the results.

Do you think is a problem related to the Java version?
And, does it make sense/is it possible to implement a custom Kafka Driver to read the data from this db? Any suggestion about this problem or how to implement a custom Kafka Driver for an old DB?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225191/issue-with-confluent-jdbc-source-connector/54225919#54225919

Comment: When I run the JDBC connector, I can see this info in the logs:

[2019-01-25 16:28:49,891] INFO Loading plugin from: /Users/confluent-5.1.0/plugins/jdbc/cloudscape.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:220)
[2019-01-25 16:28:50,008] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/confluent-5.1.0/plugins/jdbc/cloudscape.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:243)

So I think the plugins path is set correct. Any help to solve the problem? i thought the problem is the version of Java very old, but not sure.

Comment: Could you change log level, as cricket_007 suggested and attach some log to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't immediately jump to the conclusion that the driver/database is old...

You cannot point `plugin.path` directly to just the JDBC driver.

Update `plugin.path` to be the absolute path to top-level `/path/to/confluent-x.y.z/usr/share/java`, and copy your driver into `kafka-connect-jdbc` folder.

Restart Connect, then the driver should be found.

---

You can debug this futher by finding `kafka/connect-log4j.properties` and set

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
```

Then you will see logs like so (example for MySQL)

```
[2019-01-15 09:45:26,949] DEBUG Registered java.sql.Driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver@37303f12 to java.sql.DriverManager (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:277)
```

Comment: cricket_007 and @wardziniak
This is exactly what I have done:
1) created the properties file in my query above and store it in <confluent>/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc
2) export CONFLUENT_HOME
3) copied the cloudscape.jar file in <confluent>/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
4) modified the file <confluent>/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties, and added plugin.path=share/java

[Continue in the next comment...]

Comment: 5) updated the file <confluent>/etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties with TRACE mode
6) run the connector with the command: <confluent>/bin/connect-standalone <confluent>/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties <confluent>/etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/soruce-con.properties
Result: nothing change, and I don't even see any DEBUG/TRACE messages... Any idea why and help?

Comment: 1) `CONFLUENT_HOME` wasn't part of my answer... 2) `plugin.path` needs to be an **absolute path**, (start with a slash), 3) I don't know if `cloudscape.jar` contains an actual JDBC Driver. 4) `schema-registry/log4j.properties` doesn't need changed, I mentioned a different file in my answer.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I got the DEBUG messages. I have edited my original questions with the DEBUG messages (please, read above). However the Kafka-connector still not work even with the absolute path (i.e. plugin.path=/Users/userone/confluent-5.1.0/share/java). Cloudscape uses RMI and JDBC for the connection. Might it be the problem? FYI: To run a simple Java RMI client able to query the DB, I imported different .jar files (which however I have copied all them in  <confluent>/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc). Any further help?

Comment: Are you trying to run Kafka Connect on the same machine where you database is running? If not, then don't use `localhost`. If so, I'm not really sure what to tell you, but it does seem your JAR is being loaded now. I don't have really any experience with RMI

Answer (score 0):

You can alter META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver, change it , overwrited it by your Driver class.
It can work for me!